# splitting string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please help me with this task. I have a table with two columns (ID, String). String in that column is separated by '#'. And I need to produce column "Cut"[image]

Comment: Based on what please?

Comment: Asked and answered many times. But really, *why* are you storing your data like this? SQL has data types *designed* for holding multiple values. string isn't one of them. If you use a type *designed* for holding multiple values, you'll find that the mechanism for extracting individual values is also supplied.

Comment: That data was given to me in xls. I was trying to cut it in Excel, Access but with no result, so I switched to SQL Server but stucked with second '#' character - first two letters I was able to split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should to the trick. Split your string in rows and then select distinct values. If you need the `String` column also, just join your table on `id`.

```
declare @tbl as table (
    id int
    ,string varchar(25)
)

insert into @tbl values (1, 'A#B#C')
insert into @tbl values (1, 'A#B#C')
insert into @tbl values (1, 'A#B#C')
insert into @tbl values (2, 'K#L#X#W#I')
insert into @tbl values (2, 'K#L#X#W#I')
insert into @tbl values (2, 'K#L#X#W#I')
insert into @tbl values (2, 'K#L#X#W#I')
insert into @tbl values (3, 'G')



SELECT DISTINCT [Id], Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(5)') AS [Cut]  
FROM (
    SELECT [Id], CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([String], '#', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS [String]
    FROM  @tbl
) AS A CROSS APPLY [String].nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
CREATE TABLE MyStrings (
    ID INT,
    String VARCHAR (25)
    );
INSERT INTO MyStrings VALUES
(1, 'A#B#C'),
(1, 'A#B#C'),
(1, 'A#B#C'),
(2, 'K#L#X#W#I'),
(2, 'K#L#X#W#I'),
(2, 'K#L#X#W#I'),
(2, 'K#L#X#W#I'),
(2, 'K#L#X#W#I'),
(3, 'G');

WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RN
FROM MyStrings
    )
    SELECT ID, String,
            SUBSTRING(String, IIF(RN = 1 , RN, RN + (RN-1)) 
                      , 1) AS Cut
    FROM CTE;
```

OR

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *,
        REPLACE (String, '#', '') AS STR,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RN
FROM MyStrings
    )
    SELECT ID, String, SUBSTRING(STR, RN, 1) AS Cut
    FROM CTE;
```

Results:

```
+----+-----------+-----+
| ID |  String   | Cut |
+----+-----------+-----+
|  1 | A#B#C     | A   |
|  1 | A#B#C     | B   |
|  1 | A#B#C     | C   |
|  2 | K#L#X#W#I | K   |
|  2 | K#L#X#W#I | L   |
|  2 | K#L#X#W#I | X   |
|  2 | K#L#X#W#I | W   |
|  2 | K#L#X#W#I | I   |
|  3 | G         | G   |
+----+-----------+-----+
```